# Type class syntax for both Seq[A] and Map[A, Int]

Tags: scala, typeclass

I am writing a type class to represent collections of experimental observations.  My syntax trait to enrich `Seq` and `Map` seems poor.  Can it be improved?

Goal:

```
assert(5 == Seq("a", "a", "b", "b", "c").numObs)
assert(5 == Map("a" -> 2, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 1).numObs)
```

My (heavily simplified) type class:

```
trait Observations[A, T[_]] {
  def numObs(t: T[A]): Int
}
```

Instances for Seq and frequency tables:

```
object Observations{

  implicit def seqIsObservations[A]: Observations[A, Seq] = new Observations[A, Seq] {
    def numObs(t: Seq[A]) = t.size
  }

  implicit def freqTableIsObservations[A]: Observations[A, ({ type λ[A] = Map[A, Int] })#λ] = 
      new Observations[A, ({ type λ[A] = Map[A, Int] })#λ] {
    def numObs(t: Map[A, Int]) = t.values.sum
  }
}
```

The best syntax I’ve come up with:

```
trait ObservationsSyntax {

  implicit class ObservationsOps[A, T[_]](thiz: T[A]) {
    def numObs(implicit instance: Observations[A, T]): Int = 
      instance.numObs(thiz)
  }

  //Don’t like having to have this special case
  implicit class ObservationsMAPOps[A](thiz: Map[A, Int]) {
    def numObs(implicit instance: Observations[A, ({ type λ[A] = Map[A, Int] })#λ]): Int = 
      instance.numObs(thiz)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to use type lambdas to eliminate the second implicit in the syntax trait?

Comment: There really is no other way currently. This is why you see it used all over the place in projects like Scalaz or Cats.

Comment: It hurts the eyes to see that for what is really a trivial concept to achieve in a real functional programming language.